# Syntax highlighting in Astro Nvim

Tags: neovim, treesitter

I installed the Astro Vim package. Syntax highlighting should work out of the box, but it doesn't. As soon as I write `:setfiletype javascript` highlighting works immediately. Is there any way to enable automatic file type detection? I executed the LspInstall and TSInstall commands after installation

Now the editor looks like this:

[image: Now the editor looks like this]

Answer (score 4):

You are likely using Nvim v0.8.0 (released 3 days ago), which introduced several breaking changes and is incompatible with AstroNvim v1.10.0 (the current stable version; refer to [this discussion](https://github.com/AstroNvim/AstroNvim/discussions/1020)).

AstroNvim v2.0 was pushed to the project's nightly branch and will support the new Nvim release; however, seeing as it is currently unstable, for now your best option would be to **downgrade to Nvim 0.7.2**.